# Getting 403 : When access with http:site works fine with https:site

Tags: http, tomcat, web-applications, https, http-status-code-403

On landing page I have URL of a web applications. When I click on the url I am getting 403 error.While if I hit the url again it works fine for me.When I access the url of webapplication directly with https It works fine.
Webserver I am using is Tomcat.

Steps to

1. Launch http://hostname
2. Select https://hostname/Site
3. 403 forbidden message
4. Directly access https://hostame/site and it goes thru

Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like the URL of the app you are trying to reach has an access control issue/bug. Do you control that app as well?

Comment: @snkashis yeah app is under our control